# Entity framework update one column by increasing the current value by one without select

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

What I want to achieve is the simple sql query: **UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = COLUMN + 1**

Is there a way to make it happen without loading all records (thousands) to memory first and loop through each record to increment the column and then save it back?

**EDIT**

I tried raw sql and it worked. I have to decide the sql provider from the connection string and the database schema name from the connection context. After that, I will use the corresponding sql query to update the table.

For SQL, it looks like UPDATE **schemaname.TABLE SET COLUMN = COLUMN + 1**.
for POSTGRESQL, I have to double quote schema name, table name and column name: **UPDATE "schemaname"."TABLE" SET "COLUMN" = "COLUMN" + 1**.

Comment: What is the issue with running the SQL command?  (This question is tagged "sql")

Comment: `myContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = COLUMN + 1");`

Comment: I think this does what you want: https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities#update-by-query

Comment: I want to support mssql and npgsql together

Comment: I'm surprised that you couldn't get the raw SQL to work with both DBMS. Care to tell us which one failed and with what error?  I am sure someone will be able to help you with that if all else fails.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution. You can use the following code:

```
context.Table.Where(x => x.Field1 > 0).Update(y => new Table { Field2 = y.Field2 + 1 });
```

hope that it helps.

Comment: This is EF Core only

Comment: I can't see this solution in EF Core. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

With pure EF, you are right:  you have to load the entities one by one, set the property, and save.  Very inefficient.

The 2 alternatives that I know of are:

1. Provide raw SQL to execute the UPDATE statement as you want it.
2. Use the EntityFramework.Extended library (https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended), which supports both bulk UPDATEs and DELETEs with a natural EF feel.

Quote from their main page:

> **Batch Update and Delete**
>
> A current limitations of the Entity Framework is that in order to update or delete an entity you have to first retrieve it into memory. Now in most scenarios this is just fine. There are however some senerios where performance would suffer. Also, for single deletes, the object must be retrieved before it can be deleted requiring two calls to the database. Batch update and delete eliminates the need to retrieve and load an entity before modifying it.
>
> **Deleting**

```
//delete all users where FirstName matches
context.Users.Where(u => u.FirstName == "firstname").Delete();
```

> **Update**

```
//update all tasks with status of 1 to status of 2
context.Tasks.Update(
    t => t.StatusId == 1, 
    t2 => new Task {StatusId = 2});

//example of using an IQueryable as the filter for the update
var users = context.Users.Where(u => u.FirstName == "firstname");
context.Users.Update(users, u => new User {FirstName = "newfirstname"});
```

Comment: EntityFramework.Extended will not help. It's a great library but the batch  feature only lets you set columns of multiple records to the *same* value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EFCore.BulkExtensions in EFCore, solution like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42368027/8163839

```cs
context.Table.Where(x => x.Field1 > 0).BatchUpdate(y => new Table { Field2 = y.Field2 + 1 });
```

There is one small problem, the method parameters are `Expression<Func<Table, Table>>`, so you can only assign values to properties like above.

**It is not DDD friendly.**