# Entity Framework Incrementing column value without query it before

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have a sql server with the table "contacts", in this table i have column "clicks" of type int, i want to increment its value without making a query.

This is a copy of: "[Entity framework update one column by increasing the current value by one without select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609079/entity-framework-update-one-column-by-increasing-the-current-value-by-one-withou)"
the solution that suggested there is using [EntityFramework.Utilities](https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities#update-by-query)
the problem is that its not a IQueryable extension like [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) and that makes it hard to implement for me.

the question is there any other way/solution to incremenet int value on sql with using IQueryable(without actually writing sql query)?

the result of the IQueryable query should look like:

```
UPDATE Contacts SET clicks=clicks+1 WHERE id=8432
```

Comment: Look for SEQUENCE in sql server; 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: i didn't found any easy way to use sql server SEQUENCE with entity framework

Comment: You are trying to drive a screw using a hammer. What you are asking has nothing to do with sequences, IDs or entities. That means you don't have objects or mappings, hence you don't need an ORM. The correct approach would be to use eg eSQL or raw SQL to execute the UPDATE statement using parameters. Better yet, create and call a stored procedure

Comment: Another very important problem. The original code doesn't suffer from concurrency violations. It doesn't matter how many concurrent updates are made, the value is always incremented correctly. On the other hand, any attempt by multiple threads to update values on the client side and save them will result in a concurrency violation.

Comment: I can't see an equivalent solution in ef core. Do you know how it is possible with that?

Comment: @MohammadBarbast im not sure if its the same but the solution below is based on the usage of extra library that was called EF Extended, currently its called EF plus, see: https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-batch-update

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just found the solution after some research and testing, actually EntityFramework.Extended do exactly what i want it to do, if you want to increment a column just call the Update method with adding assignment:

```
db.Contacts.Where(c => c.Id == id).Update(c => new Contact { Clicks = c.Clicks + 1 });
```

After checking the source code of EntityFramework.Extended and debugging it i saw that the query that executed in the end is exactly what i wanted,
so thanks everybody for trying to help, the solution were right under my nose ;-)

Comment: This package has been deprecated as it is legacy and is no longer maintained.