# How to Perform Mathematical Operations to an Entity Without It Being Changed Externally?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After I get the entity value, the quantity might have already been changed externally. How do I lock the value so after I save the entity, it will just add to the previous value?

```
stock_info stockInfoEntity = dbStock.stock_info.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
stockInfoEntity.Quantity = stockInfoEntity.Quantity + quantityAdditional;
dbStock.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609079/entity-framework-update-one-column-by-increasing-the-current-value-by-one-withou

Comment: Implement optimistic concurrency. If you get a concurrency exception, just refetch & reassign the value and save again.